# How to get all movies from OMDb?

Tags: ajax, http

So I can get a single query with, for example:

```
`http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=inception`
```

How do I get all the movies from the api?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does IMDb provide an api or a data dump to get all title IDs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462949/does-imdb-provide-an-api-or-a-data-dump-to-get-all-title-ids)

Comment: Yes both `i` and `t` parameters will return only one result.

Comment: are you asking for "all the movies with 'inception' in its title" or for "all movies" in general?

Answer (score 8):

You can't get all the movies from OMDb API, even if you use `*` it will return an error `Too many results.`

But you can return multiple results using `s` parameter. Look at the code sample below using jQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ajax Request</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=inception&apikey=[yourkey]", function(data) {
        console.table(data);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Check your browser console to view the result.